# Linq query to get row data as columns

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am developing one MVC4 application. I am working on one complex query and practically I do not know this is possible or not. I will explain the scenario and i will put what i tried so far. 
I have one log log table in SQL and structure is as below.

```
ID   uploadID   docType   updateVersion  FieldName     FieldValue    Status
1    1          Passport       1         Docnumber     123          NotVerified
2    1          Passport       1         Expirydate    01/01/2016   NotVerified
3    1          Passport       2         Docnumber     456          Rejected
4    1          Passport       2         Expirydate    01/01/2017   Rejected
5    1          Passport       3         Docnumber     789          Approved
6    1          Passport       3         Expirydate    01/01/2019   Approved
```

This is my log table. For example passport will contain field Docnumber and expirydate. When it is uploaded initially it is not verified. Later admin rejects it and approves it. Each operations I am maintaining updateVersion. Now i want result as below.

```
ID  uploadID  docType   FieldName  OldValue    NewValue    OldStatus   newStatus
1   1         Passport  Docnumber  123         789         NotVerified Approved
2   1         Passport  Expirydate 01/01/2016  01/01/2019  NotVerified Approved.
```

In the resultant table I am expecting old values,new values,old status and new status. I am keeping track of each entry by updateVersion. however i want to display for perticular upldId initial values and last updated values only. I want to skip middle values. Can someone tell me this can be achieved in LINQ or Do i need to use any other logic? Thank you all.

Comment: Would have been a lot easier had you set up the database to replace `FieldValue` and `Status` with `NotVerifiedValue`, `RejectedValue` and `ApprovedValue`

Comment: I want to show it in webpage. Do i need to create temporary table with  FieldValue,Status,NotVerifiedValue,RejectedValue ,ApprovedValue  fields?

Comment: I was just commenting that it would have been easier had you set up the table initially with the fields as I noted above :)

Comment: No. I have not prepared fields as you said. If i prepare table as you said definitly it is very easy to query it. So can i go ahead with the same?

Comment: I don't know enough about what your wanting to log, so can't be sure. Personally I would have 2 tables, one to identify the document and the field, and a second table with value, status and FK to the first table (and you could have additional columns for the date, the person who approved it etc.

Comment: I guess you could define a view in your database, which will severe you as data source for your application. LINQ is powerful and I think it can be done, but in my opinion it would be harder to maintain (maybe even less performant).

Comment: What is the best approach to solve this?